# Django Form is not processing properly and no error has been displayed

Tags: django, forms

Trying to create an app that saves sales in different sateges for  my team(similar to an ecommerce)
however the  form to add the account info is not saving the data...

I review different options and use formset as well no changes.

model.py

```
TYPE=(
    ('delegated','Delegated'),
    ('not_delegated','Not Delegated')
)

class Account(models.Model):
    agent_profile=models.ForeignKey(AgentProfile, on_delete= CASCADE)
    account_name=models.CharField(max_length=120)
    opp_type=models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=TYPE, default='not_delegated')
    bp_id=models.IntegerField()
    mdm_id=models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True,blank=True)
    AM=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.agent_profile)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Account

class AccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Account
        fields=[
            #'agent_profile',
            'account_name',
            'opp_type',
            'bp_id',
            'mdm_id',
            'AM'
        ]

views.py


def confirm_account_create_view(request):
    form=AccountForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    next_ = request.GET.get('next')
    next_post = request.POST.get('next')
    redirect_path = next_ or next_post or None
    if form.is_valid():
        instance=form.save(commit=False)
        agent_profile, agent_profile_created = AgentProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)

        if agent_profile is not None:
            opp_type = request.POST.get('delegate_opp', 'not_delegated_opp')
            instance.agent_profile = agent_profile
            instance.opp_type = opp_type
            instance.save()
            request.session[opp_type + "_opp_id"] = instance.id
            print(opp_type + "_opp_id")
    
        else:
            print("Please verify Form")
            return redirect("opps:confirm")

        if is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
            return redirect(redirect_path)

    return redirect("opps:confirm")
```

urls.py (main app)

path('orders/confirm/account', confirm_account_create_view, name='create_account'),

form page(HTML)
 {% csrf_token %}
{% if next_url %}

{% endif %}

```
  {% if opp_type %}
  <input type='hidden' name='opp_type' value='{{ opp_type }}' />
  {% endif %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

confirm page(HTML)
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

```
{% block content %}

{{ object.order_id }} --{{object.opp}}
<div class="pb-9 mb-7 text-center border-b border-black border-opacity-5">
  
  <h2 class="mb-7 lg:mt-6 text-3xl font-heading font-medium">Confirm Info</h2>
</div>
  <h2 class="mb-7 lg:mt-6 text-3xl font-heading font-medium">Account</h2>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between py-4 px-10 mb-3 leading-8 bg-white bg-opacity-50 font-heading font-medium rounded-3xl">
      {% if not object.delegated_opp %}
        {% url "create_account" as confirm_account_create_view%}
        {% include 'accounts/form.html' with form=delegated_form ext_url=request.build_absolute_uri action_url=confirm_account_create_view opp_type='not_delegated_opp' %}
    </div>
    
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between py-4 px-10 mb-3 leading-8 bg-white bg-opacity-50 font-heading font-medium rounded-3xl">
      {% elif not object.not_delegated_opp %}
        {% url "create_account" as confirm_account_create_view%}
        {% include 'accounts/form.html' with form=delegated_form ext_url=request.build_absolute_uri action_url=confirm_account_create_view opp_type='not_delegated_opp' %}
      </div>
  </div>
      {%else%}
             
        <div>
          <h2 class="mb-7 lg:mt-6 text-3xl font-heading font-medium">Order summary</h2>
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between py-4 px-10 mb-3 leading-8 bg-white bg-opacity-50 font-heading font-medium rounded-3xl">
            <span>Subtotal</span>
            <span class="flex items-center text-xl">
              <span class="mr-2 text-base">$</span>
              <span>{{object.opp.subtotal}}</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between py-4 px-10 mb-3 leading-8 bg-white bg-opacity-50 font-heading font-medium rounded-3xl">
            <span>Discount</span>
            <span class="flex items-center text-xl">
              <span class="mr-2 text-base">$</span>
              <span>{{object.discount}}</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div class="flex items-center justify-between py-4 px-10 mb-14 leading-8 bg-white font-heading font-medium rounded-3xl">
            <span>Total</span>
            <span class="flex items-center text-xl text-blue-500">
              <span class="mr-2 text-base">$</span>
              <span>{{object.total}}</span>
            </span>
          </div>
          
          
          <a class="inline-block w-full py-5 lg:py-3 px-10 text-lg leading-6 lg:leading-7 text-white font-medium tracking-tighter font-heading text-center bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-xl" href="#">Save Opp</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="md:w-96"><a class="block py-5 px-10 w-full text-xl leading-6 font-medium tracking-tighter font-heading text-center bg-white hover:bg-gray-50 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:ring-opacity-50 rounded-xl" href="#">Back to top</a></div>
    </div>
    </section>
{% endif %}
```

{% endblock content %}

Answer (score 0):

I type AM by mistake instead of am at a model level and form level.
Once I changed it to :

am=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)

It began to work properly